# Resistors in audio circuit

Tags: resistors, audio

I have a question regarding an audio circuit that I have. This is the general/simplified schematic:

[image]

Pretty much what is happening in this circuit is the black is what was previously on the circuit. There is an AUDIO PCB (Audio #1) that sends signals to the processing unit (Mono Out). This only happens when SW1 is closed and it goes through a resistor of unknown value. The Mono Out sends audio signals to a headset to play a sound.

The red is an additional Audio PCB (Audio #2) that was spliced to the circuit.

The issue I am currently running into is that when SW1 is open, the sound that plays is very loud. When SW1 is closed, the sound is quieter. I'm assuming that this is due to Audio #2 not having a resistor to limit any audio clipping and therefore with SW1 open, the sound is louder.

So my question: Would adding a resistor (see image below) to the Audio #2 splice mitigate the difference in sound levels when the Switch is open vs closed?
Another question: If a resistor would help, how would I go about sizing the resistor? Should it be equal to R1 or would it depend on Audio #2?

The same audio is played through the speaker for both PCB's as an FYI. There is only 1 audio that gets played.

[image]

Comment: why don't  you try it?

Comment: We cannot know the output impedances of your mystery devices. Or the mystery device loading the output. The problem is, when the switch is on or off, it will add load or disconnect load to output #2. So anyway the volume is  different with the switch on or off.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Depends on output impedance of Audio #1 and #2 and input impedance of whatever is connected to Mono out.

Answer (score 1):

When you say the audio is louder when the switch is open there are two possibilities.

1. You mean that when the switch is open only Audio #2 is being used, and when the switch is closed only Audio #1 is being used.
2. You mean that with only Audio #2 being used its volume goes down when you close the switch.

In the first case adding a resistor should help reduce the level of Audio #2, you would probably need to determine the best value resistor by experimentation, or use a variable resistor.

In the second case what would be happening is that Audio #2 is getting loaded down by Audio #1 when the switch is closed, in that case a resistor would make it worse. The solution there would be to use a SPDT switch to only connect either Audio #1 or Audio #2 but never both. You may still need a resistor for Audio #2 to balance the levels though.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Qq8s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Probably the best way to do it would be to use a SPDT switch and put a volume control on each audio source so you could adjust them individually. Since the volume controls would have a DC path to ground you might need to use blocking capacitors as shown here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj3xV1.png)</sup>